# PHP get subset from an multilevel Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array (simplified):

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [id1] => 0
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [id1] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1001
                        [id1] => 2
                    )
            )
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [id1] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [1002] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1002
                        [id1] => 2
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [1002] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1002
                                        [id1] => 2
                                    )
                                [1003] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1003
                                        [id1] => 2
                                    )
                             )
                    )
                [1003] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1003
                        [id1] => 2
                    )
            )
    )
```

I would like to select a section of it (as an Array), with all the children attached to it.

Example 1 (key 3, infinite depth):

```
$result = getArrayKey(3, $dept = 0);

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [id1] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [1002] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1002
                        [id1] => 2
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [1002] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1002
                                        [id1] => 2
                                    )
                                [1003] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1003
                                        [id1] => 2
                                    )
                             )
                    )
                [1003] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1003
                        [id1] => 2
                    )
            )
```

Example 2 (key 3, dept 1):

```
$result = getArrayKey(3, $dept = 1);

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [id1] => 0
    )
```

Example 3 (key 3, infinite depth):

```
$result = getArrayKey(1002, $dept = 0);

[1002] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1002
        [id1] => 2
        [children] => Array
            (
                [1002] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1002
                        [id1] => 2
                    )
                [1003] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1003
                        [id1] => 2
                    )
            )
    )
```

I can walk over this Array and save the needed levels to a new Array I think, but is there a more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to write a recursive function that iterates over the whole array and drags the depth along to decide for every sub-array if it should be included into the result. Using 0 for "everything" is highly impractical. In my solution you either don't give a depth or use a negative value to retrieve everything.

```
function getSubArray (array $array, $key, $depth = -1) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array[$key] as $k => $v) {
       if (is_array($v) && ($depth != 0)) {
           $result[$k] = getSubArray($array[$key], $k, ($depth - 1));
       } else {
           $result[$k] = $v;
       }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...I saw that too late. The huge code blocks confused me. ;) I changed my answer already though.

Comment: Can you make a small edit so that I can remove my downvote? :P

Comment: is this taking into consideration that he wants 0 to go all the way?

Comment: It didn't, but now it does if no depth is given.

Comment: i suggest to use -1 as the indefinite depth marker and add that condition it to the if

Comment: Mmmm. It works when I select a key at the highest level of the array. When I select a key in a deeper branch it could not find the key (Like example 3). In that case $array[$key] is not an array and gives an error.

Comment: I guess I overlooked that example of yours. But in that case what you want is difficult to achive. What should the function do if you choose a key that exists on several levels of the array?

Comment: The keys are in fact the unique ID field of the table. It's difficult indeed, I am cracking my head all day over it...

Comment: Well...you can always do a recursive search for the key in all subarrays (similar to my function) and then call my function on that key for the specific subarray. Only question remaining then is if the depth is counted from root or from the subarray. And of course that only works if the keys truly are unique.